# Как выбрать оптимальный сервер для REST-приложения на php

Tags: php, сервер, rest

Есть rest приложение на php, в котором запускается много долгоживущих php-процессов (от 15 до 40 минут). Как подобрать оптимальный сервер для приложения и протестировать нагрузку?

Какой инструмент лучше использовать для тестирования, чтобы можно было создать или имитировать большое количество этих процессов? К тому же сам процесс php работает с comet-сервером centrifugo, на каждый процесс создается канал в центрифуге, и процесс шлет в канал сообщения.

Comment: В принципе любой из существующих нагрузочно-тестирующих инструментов/библиотек - JMeter, Locust.io, LoadUI, Postman, Gatling или другие. Использовали Locust, нам он пока что подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как любят отвечать англоязычные эксперты по любому продукту: **depends**.

Все зависит от конкретных условий: что есть, что планируется достичь, какая база используется, к чему все это и т.д. Сейчас очень актуальны облачные сервера(с любыми параметрами), поэтому возьмите 2 инстанса, установите apache и nginx, и тестируйте ваше приложение.

Вам подсказали в комментариях какие инструменты для тестирования использовать.

Пример использования [JMeter](https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/23/jmeter-rest-api-testing/)

Пример использования [SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/getting-started.html)

Postman из разряда must have!